# Touchpad doesnt work on lapbook air Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I'm trying to give a new life to my Chuwi lapbook air and after I had installed ubuntu 19.04 the touchpad doesnt work.

I saw a that the problem is known but I didnt found anything about a final resolution.

In my case the touchpad is detected by the computer, here the *xinput*:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS0001:00 0911:5288 Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse          id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is what is inside */proc/bus/input/devices*:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0911 Product=5288 Version=0100
N: Name="ALPS0001:00 0911:5288 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ALPS0001:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/i2c_designware.4/i2c-5/i2c-ALPS0001:00/0018:0911:5288.0001/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e420 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

I think I use xserver-xorg-input-libinput for the driver (?) and this is the result of *xinput list-props 'ALPS0001:00 0911:5288 Touchpad'*:

```
Device 'ALPS0001:00 0911:5288 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (154):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (156): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (307): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (308): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (309):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (310):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (311):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (312):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (313):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (314):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (289):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (290):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (315):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (316):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (291):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (292):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (293):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (317): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (318):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (319):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (296):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (297):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (298): 0.452555
    libinput Accel Speed Default (299): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (303): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (304): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (274): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (275):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (276):    0, 0
    Device Node (277):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (278):    2321, 21128
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (305):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (306):   1
```

It sometimes works for a few seconds and if I use the external mouse or if I stop to use the touchpad for more than 5 sec it don't restart.

any ideas?

(kernel version 5.0.0-16-generic)